# How to override a prop component used as props in the returned component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm coding a component to facility the use of material-ui React Autocomplete component, It new component has a few props then return the React Autocomplete component with  its own props assigned, how Can I override the React Autocomplete prop "onChange" in some situations where I need to add additional code lines?

```
import React from 'react';
import './CustomAutocomplete.css';
import { Autocomplete, createFilterOptions } from '@material-ui/lab';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';

interface CustomAutocompleteProps {
  placeholder: string;
  options: any[];
  optionSelected: any;
  setOptionSelected: (newValue: any) => void;
  startSearchLength: number;
  optionsSuggestionLimit: number;
}

export const CustomAutocomplete = (props: CustomAutocompleteProps) => {
  const defaultFilterOptions = createFilterOptions();
  const filterOptions = (options, state) => {
    return defaultFilterOptions(options, state).slice(
      0,
      props.optionsSuggestionLimit
    );
  };

  return (
    <Autocomplete
      placeholder={props.placeholder}
      filterOptions={filterOptions}
      value={
        props.options.length === 1 ? props.options[0] : props.optionSelected
      }
      options={props.options ? props.options : []}
      disabled={props.options.length === 1}
      getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.name === value.name}
      getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name || ''}
      onChange={(event: any, newValue: any) => {
        props.setOptionSelected(newValue);
      }}
      renderInput={(params) => (
        <TextField
          {...params}
          variant="standard"
          placeholder={props.placeholder}
          onChange={(event: any) => {
            event.target.value.length > props.optionsSuggestionLimit &&
              props.setOptionSelected(event.target.value);
          }}
        />
      )}
    />
  );
};
```

In some cases I need to add more set useState in onChange props but if I add it in the CustomAutocomplete component it will attempt to execute in every import. How can I overried and called just in a specific situation?

```
onChange={(event: any, newValue: any) => {
        setOptionSelected(newValue);
setoptionSelected2(newValue);
setOptionSelected3(newValue);
      }}
```

Do you have any idea? Thanks!

Comment: Why can't you use a prop passed to `CustomAutocomplete` to determine which version of `onChange` to use?

Comment: How Can I code it? I'm stuck

Comment: Using props to drive component behavior is fundamental to React development. You should spend more time researching and reading code before getting an answer for this.

Comment: But this is not the point. I need to override the principal props and then pass to child component "Autocomplete"